# ADF - selectOneChoice - Fire always valueChangeListener if it has not change

Tags: jsp, jsf, oracle-adf, adfs

i've one "selectOneChoice" and i want that valueChangeListener wil be fire even if it has not change.

```
<af:selectOneChoice styleClass="sp_js_carousselTrigger fks_#{item.mediaId}"
                                        valueChangeListener="#{SP_MediaPlayer_MB.categorizarImagenes}"
                                        id="comboCategoria" autoSubmit="true">
                        <af:selectItem label="Con motivo todo en orden" value="SeeAllInOrderWithReason" id="si7"/>
                        <af:selectItem label="Sin motivo todo en orden" value="SeeAllInOrderWithoutReason" id="si8"/>
                        <af:selectItem label="Se ven personas" value="SeePeople" id="si9"/>
                        <af:selectItem label="Acto delictivo" value="FCS" id="si10"/>
                        <af:selectItem label="No se ve claro" value="NotSeeClear" id="si11"/>
                        <f:attribute name="param" value="#{item.mediaId}"/>
                        <f:attribute name="param_zone" value="#{item.captureZone}"/>
                    </af:selectOneChoice>
```

Is there any option?

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation and understanding is incorrect regarding the 'ValueChange' event.
The 'ValueChange' event will be fired only the when the value changes.

Otherwise , you need to programmatically 'Queue' the value change event.